# Android items background automatically change

Tags: android, list, background, drawable, slidingmenu

today i was implementing a new feature in my app: showing a dialog with an EditText and requesting the soft keyboard, and i notice something really strange with my items in the sliding menu (I'm using the library from jfeinstein10)...

When the dialog shows and not the keyboard the items inside the sliding menu are okay, but when i also show the keyboard, the items change their background resource...

I tried using the log in the item click listener of the list inside the sliding menu but nothing it's called... So... Why it automatically change the background ?!

Hope you can help me :) And sorry for my english :D

The item click listener inside the sliding menu:

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener slidingListItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            // Unselected items
            for (int j = 0; j < adapterView.getChildCount(); j++) {
                View root = adapterView.getChildAt(j);

                ImageView image = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.partial_sliding_menu_list_image);
                TextView text = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.partial_sliding_menu_list_text);

                image.setBackgroundResource(SLIDING_MENU_ICON_NORMAL);
                text.setTextColor( getResources().getColor(SLIDING_MENU_TEXT_NORMAL) );
            }

            // change the drawable of the selected item
            ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.partial_sliding_menu_list_image);
            TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.partial_sliding_menu_list_text);

            image.setBackgroundResource(SLIDING_MENU_ICON_SELECTED);
            text.setTextColor( getResources().getColor(SLIDING_MENU_TEXT_SELECTED) );

            // Load the page clicked [it's a fragment.]
            loadPage(i);
        }
    };
```

Some screenshots of the "error":

[Click me](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7l4bsr6fx1asexw/AACWebKOH5jaTEDEokdkNDSBa?dl=0)

Comment: Can you show us the getView code of your adapter? Because the problem is that the keyboard will make the adapter redraw it's views. And since you don't maintain a state to its state (selected or unselected) the getView will get called for the visible items and therefore the background will get all messy

Comment: Thank you very much! It was so obvious... Resolved using a private variable for the current selected index and refreshing the list with the notifyDataSetChanged of the adapter - where the bg res are being set. Now it works perfectly :) Have a good day !!!